# Automatically resize image effect in CSS3

Tags: css, animation, image-resizing

I have an image of 200 x 200. I want my image to have 2 effects:
    1. The image floats slowly into the center of the `<div>` (320x240px)
    2. Right after that, it will automatically resize 50% (which is 100x100px) and float into left-bottom of the `<div>`

Here is my code:

```
#ad-1 #alunaimg{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 20px 60px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-animation: imgmove 3s linear 0s 1;
-webkit-animation: imgresize 2s linear 0s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imgmove{
0%   {left: -200px; top: 0px;}
100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes imgresize{
0%  {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
100% {width: 50%; height: 50%; top: 130px; left: 40px;}

}
```

The first effect works perfectly, but the second effect does not work.

Here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/DreamBig/pgQhJ

I would appreciate if anyone could help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is always going to be the sequence, you may want to consider putting the whole thing into a single animation, otherwise you're going to have to use javascript and assign a new class to trigger the second animation.

```
@-webkit-keyframes imgmove{
    0%   {left: -200px; top: 0px;}
    50% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    100% {width: 50%; height: 50%; top: 130px; left: 40px;}
}
```

This is completely untested, but you can't add multiple animations like that. If you're going to keep it separate, I think you can try:

```
-webkit-animation: imgmove 3s linear 0s 1, imgresize 2s linear 3s 1;
```

Note the `3s` delay on the second animation which will make it happen directly after the first animation.

As an aside, I would maybe consider using css transforms instead of `left` and `top`. See http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/.

Is this any closer: http://jsfiddle.net/pgQhJ/2/

```
#ad-1 #alunaimg{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px 60px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: imgmove 3s linear 0s;
    top: 20px; left: -40px; width: 50%; height: 50%;
}
#ad-1 #alunaimg img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imgmove{
    0%   {left: -200px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    50% {left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    100% {top: 20px; left: -40px; width: 50%; height: 50%; }
}
```

I set the `#alunaimg` div to be the same as 100% of your animation so that at the end it stays where it was, which also meant adding `width` and `height` to the other keyframes in the animation.

Comment: I've tested. The second image transition works (top: 130px; left: 40px) but it still does not resize 50%. Many thanks, that helps a lot!

Comment: Do you have a link or perhaps can make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so I can get a better idea of how things are happening now?

Comment: I've created jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DreamBig/pgQhJ. Could you take a look for me?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is this:

```
<div id="ad-1">
    <div id="alunaimg">
        <img></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

You are changing alunaimg dimensions, but not the inner img dimensions.

Add

```
#alunaimg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

To make the img adapt to the dimensions of the container div